# Invoking one css selector from another selector

Tags: css

I have two selectors below

```
.buttonLiteblue
    {
    background-color: #99CCFF; 
    }
.buttonxyz
    {
    background-color: #54564; 
    }
```

My application is using the first selector .
I want to integrate my app with other application which has second selector and i want to use the definition of second selector with out effecting all my jsp's.

something like

```
.buttonLiteblue
    {
    .buttonxyz
    }
```

Could some one please suggest..

Comment: This question doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Do you not just want `.buttonLiteblue, .buttonxyz { background-color: #54564; }`?

Comment: So you want to overwrite color of `buttonLiteblue` with the one from `buttonxyz`?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting is not supported on CSS. You could try using SASS for that effect.